# put() throwing error while unit testing NDB based Flask app in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, flask, nose

I am creating user profile in unit test case and trying to save it. Here is the code:

```
def create_user(self, email, user_id, is_admin=False):

    self.testbed.setup_env(
        USER_EMAIL = email,
        USER_ID = user_id,
        USER_IS_ADMIN = '1' if is_admin else '0',
        overwrite = True)
    user = users.get_current_user()
    print "user:", user
    u = UserProf( id=str(user.user_id()),
                  nickname = "Test",
                  email_address = user.email() )
    u.put()
```

I am calling this function while executing test case as:

```
def test_users(self):

    self.create_user('test@example.com', '123', True)
    result = self.app('/users/')
    self.assertTrue("Test" in result)
```

u.put() is causing problem. Error:

BadKeyError: Entity key differs from the one returned by the datastore. Expected Key('UserProf', '123'), got Key('UserProf', '123')

Full stacktrace, its big:

https://gist.github.com/rajendrakrp/5705313

I didn't find any thing related to this error in net. Except one, he is also reporting same problem: https://gist.github.com/sivy/3364880

Thanks.

Update: added model class of UserProf.

```
class UserProf(ndb.Model):

    nickname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email_address = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    is_admin = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    teams = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
    is_manager = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

Comment: Can you post your Model code please ?

Comment: @codegeek: Updated the question with model code.

Comment: where is the userid in your model ? I don't see it. I am guessing that you are creating a UserProf with userid as string while it should be an integer ?

Comment: id is user_id. In NDB we can 'id' can store string or integer.

Comment: I just tested in interactive console in local development server, it works fine. It is not working when done through unit test case.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had this same problem for the last few hours, I ended up running my tests with nose-gae and the flag "--without-sandbox" as indicated in this bug issue https://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/issues/detail?id=60

I realise this is an old question, but I thought I would post this in the event that it might help anyone else with testing ndb with this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the stubs for the services you want to use in your unit tests, datastore included.

```py
class DemoTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    # First, create an instance of the Testbed class.
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    # Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
    self.testbed.activate()
    # Next, declare which service stubs you want to use.
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
    self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
```